# Matplotlib: which parameter control plot to the right side?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, ipython

There is always some margin left, and it's not the "margin" in plot function controls this

[image: sample]

update:

here's the code for it, e is a pandas dataframe object

```
def tplot(e):
    f = e.copy()
    x = [str(s)[5:-7] for s in f.index]
    ff = f.set_index(pd.Series(x))
    ff.index.name = 'Time'
    ax = ff.plot()
    y_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)
    plt.xticks(rotation=30)
    return ax
```

Comment: do you mean at the RIGHT of the end of your blue line? Have you tried using `xlim` or `ax.set_xlim()`? do you mean at the left of the `y` axis? have you tried `subplots_adjust(left=0)`?

Comment: Try to check the set_data_interval (http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html). With this function you can adjust the x axis range to correctly fit your data.

Comment: It is the auto-limit/ticker code.  It is trying to make sure that it can fit an integer number of 'nice' ticks and does so by padding on the right.  It looks like in this graph you are already adjusting the ticks by hand.

Comment: and it is in general best to include a minimal (code) example which will demonstrate your problem.

Comment: updated with code, If I don't convert index to string, it's fine.